# Finding offset between two datasets containing outliers

Tags: timestamp, regression, offset, matching, ransac

Say I have the following lists of points, sorted by timestamps:

```
A = [10, 10, 10, 20, 15, 15, 5, 25]
B = [5, 5, 15, 10, 10, 0, 0, 20]
```

I am trying to match elements between the two arrays, assuming there is some unknown offset, as well as some non-matches. If I were to simply take the difference of these arrays, I would get:

```
C = A - B = [5, 5, -5, 10, 5, 15, 5, 5]
```

which doesn't show much of a pattern. However, if I realize to omit `A[2]` and `B[6]`, I would have:

```
A = [10, 10, 20, 15, 15, 5, 25]
B = [5, 5, 15, 10, 10, 0, 20]
C = [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Any ideas on how to find this offset (in this case, 5)? It is not necessarily the median, and I don't want it to simply be the mode because the solution should extend to the case where the offset is in a small range (between 4.5 and 5.5, for example). I was thinking RANSAC (with coefficient a = 1) could be helpful, but am not too sure. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I tried using "robust" regression, where I fit a straight line to the data using a fitting target of lowest sum of absolute value of error rather than the standard sum of squared errors. With your A and B values and the straight line equation "B = a + (b * A)" this yields fitted values for a and b of:

```
a = -4.9999999999999991E+00
b =  1.0000000000000000E+00
```

which is effectively "B = A - 5"

[image: plot]

Comment: What if instead the data was something like A = [100, 10, 50, 170, 400, 3000], B = [5, 45, 165, 395, 2995, 0]. In this case, the offset I'm looking for is still 5, but you don't have any "nice" data points to fit around since the first element in A is a non-match which shifts everything over (The other non-match is 0 in B). Originally, the offset array would be C = [95, -35, -115, -15, -2595, 3000] (no pattern), but after removing the outliers, A[0] and B[5], the offset is C = [5, 5, 5, 5, 5].

Comment: I agree with you, that change to the data is not the same as the first case.